# Nuget pack many dlls - final size of each package are the same

Tags: c#, dll, nuget

I have been looking for a way to get my hands on some c# projects, but the references have been mismanaged, there are references to projects / dlls with wrong paths.
I've recovered all the .dll files and I would like to create a locally hosted nuget package for each dll.
For that I created a script to make the commands

```
nuget spec "file.dll"
nuget pack "file.nuspec" -Symbols -p description="DLL file to nuget package"
```

the nuspec file generated :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>WPFToolkit.dll</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>auth</authors>
    <owners>auth</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="expression">MIT</license>
    <projectUrl>http://project_url_here_or_delete_this_line/</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://icon_url_here_or_delete_this_line/</iconUrl>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2021</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.1">
        <dependency id="SampleDependency" version="1.0.0" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

It works but my dll are between 9kb and 40kb but all the generated packages (.nupkg) are exactly 25467kb

Can you confirm that what I did is correct or am I missing something?
And how to specify the targetFramework="net45" in nuspec ?
Thank

I have already used spec + pack with csproj and the .nupkg is not so big and not have the same size
My script for each dll file in my folder

[image: Screenshot]

```
for %%f in (*.*) do (
echo %%~nf
nuget spec "%%~nf.dll"
nuget pack "%%~nf.dll.nuspec" -Symbols -p description="DLL file to nuget package"
)
```

Comment: Open up your generated nuget packages and see what's in them: change the extension to `.zip`, and unzip them

Comment: You probably include all files in "file.nuspec" so that each contains all DLL. Review "file.nuspec". Unzip as suggested by @canton7

Comment: Thank for reply , i checked that and i have only one dll but the target is incorrect
I added nuspec file on the question

Comment: Is it the correct DLL? What else is there which makes the nuget package so large?

Comment: I think it's because the dll added into the package is not my dll
<dependency id="SampleDependency" version="1.0.0" />
It's exmplain why all package have the same size 
But i dont know how to add custom dll to the nunspec with for while :/